# Connecting to Google Cloud SQL from Eclipse Not Using App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

We are trying to connect to Google Cloud SQL from Eclipse using the Database Development perspective. To do so I'm trying to add a new Database Connection, which I was able to do successfully for a local MySQL instance running on my machine.

The motivation for doing this is that we currently run our JUnit tests against the local instance. However, we are switching to Hibernate and want to make sure that all of our configuration files work with Cloud SQL. As a general guide I've been using:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/using_hibernate

We're diverging slightly in that we're using hibernate.cfg.xml instead of persistence.xml, but I don't think this will actually have a bearing on the current issue of simply connecting to the database. From another answer as well as some Google documentation I'm aware that I can't use the com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver, because that needs to be run from an AppEngine instance. Instead I'm trying to follow the directions here:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/external

and am using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.

I have assigned my Cloud SQL instance an ip address and have added my current ip address to the whitelist, as described here:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/access-control#appaccess

My driver is the Connector/J driver I've been using successfully with the local instance, and the url I'm using is:

jdbc:google:rdbms://my-app:my-cloud-sql-instance/myDatabase

which I got based on:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/using_hibernate

After adding the connection and setting the information I click Test Connection, which worked successfully on my local instance. However, this throws the following error:

```
java.lang.Exception: Connection failed with unspecified error.
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.mysql.connection.JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Obviously this isn't very helpful.

I've tried fiddling with the url, tried a number of users (none of which require passwords, so I'm leaving the password fields blank), and different versions of the driver for different versions of MySQL. Nothing has worked.

There are perhaps more deep-seated issues with doing it this way, such as how I will easily switch between test and deployment versions of my hibernate.cfg.xml, and I don't have good answers. I was just planning on editing them by hand back to the AppEngineDriver, which means I might run into further configuration issues at that point even if the JUnit tests are passing. Nevertheless, I think getting a connection set up to Cloud SQL that will allow JUnit testing will be a step in the right direction. I'd appreciate any input!

Comment: So where are you entering the IP of the cloud sql instance you're trying to connect? 

I believe that that connection string (which uses your cloud sql instance name) will only work from AppEngine.

Comment: What a doofus I am. That was exactly the problem. That is comforting in that the connection string now seems considerably less opaque. The working url is "jdbc:mysql://myCloudSqlIpAddress:3306/myDatabaseName". Juan, if you add your comment as a solution I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `jdbc:mysql://<cloudsql-instance-ip>:3306/<database-name>` to connect from an external network. The connection string you are using is to connect from Google App Engine.