# jdbc mysql communications link failure to remote database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I am trying to connect to `mysql` database using `jdbc` in my `java` program. I am using a RHEL 6 machine to connect to the mysql database. I have opened the port 3306 in this machine and if I do, `mysql -u root -p` the mysql database connects.

If I do, `mysql -h servername.edu -u root -p` the mysql database connects.

From my java program,

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
```

Works.

Now, if I change the localhost to servername, it doesn't work.

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://server.com:3306/";
```

I get the error as,

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure to remote databse
```

Before posting the question, I did a fair bit of research on this exception from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql).

I have setup the `my.cnf` file correctly and I do not see an issue in that file. What am I missing here? The normal `ping` to the server works fine as well.

Comment: the url must be like:  String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabaseName";

In your code not exist database name

Comment: also you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065653/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception

And
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql/2840358#2840358

Answer (score 0):

> CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

You can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql/2840358#2840358) which also contains good tutorial about your problem:

> If you get a SQLException: Connection refused or Connection timed out
>   or a MySQL specific CommunicationsException:    Communications link
>   failure, then it means that the DB isn't reachable at all. This can
>   have one or more of the following causes:
>
> 1. IP address or hostname in JDBC URL is wrong.
> 2. Hostname in JDBC URL is not recognized by local DNS server.
> 3. Port number is missing or wrong in JDBC URL.
> 4. DB server is down.
> 5. DB server doesn't accept TCP/IP connections.
> 6. DB server has run out of connections.
> 7. Something in between Java and DB is blocking connections, e.g. a firewall or proxy.
>
> To solve the one or the other, follow the following advices:
>
> 1. Verify and test them with ping.
> 2. Refresh DNS or use IP address in JDBC URL instead.
> 3. Verify it based on my.cnf of MySQL DB.
> 4. Start the DB.
> 5. Verify if mysqld is started without the --skip-networking option.
> 6. Restart the DB and fix your code accordingly that it closes connections in finally.
> 7. Disable firewall and/or configure firewall/proxy to allow/forward the port

Comment: How do I verify if existing instance was started without --skip-networking?