# SQOOP QUERY: trouble connecting to remote server MySQL

Tags: mysql, hadoop, jdbc, sqoop

I have a case where I need sqoop to connect to remote ipaddress mysql.
    I can  connect to mysql from putty by firing this command:

`mysql -u ro -p -h x.x.x.x -P 4307 orders --enable-cleartext-plugin`

But, I cannot  connect to remote ip : x.x.x.x from sqoop
    I am getting **`Communications link failure error`**. I think the cause of this error can be : SSL Certificate Expired as we are connecting to remote server.
    Below is the log of error generated. Even if I turned ssl option off in sqoop, it says that Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ssl is required when using cleartext authentication
    Can sqoop connect to remote server mysql?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

> Command: sqoop list-tables --connect
>   'jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:4307/orders' --username abc --password abc
>
> Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../hbase does not exist! HBase imports will
>   fail. Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
>   Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will
>   fail. Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
>   Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports
>   will fail. Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo
>   installation. Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../zookeeper does not exist!
>   Accumulo imports will fail. Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of
>   your Zookeeper installation. 18/07/10 12:18:45 INFO sqoop.Sqoop:
>   Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7 18/07/10 12:18:45 WARN
>   tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is
>   insecure. Consider using -P instead. 18/07/10 12:18:45 INFO
>   manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
>   Tue Jul 10 12:18:46 EDT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without
>   server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL
>   5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance
>   with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate
>   property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL
>   by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for
>   server certificate verification. 18/07/10 12:18:46 ERROR
>   manager.CatalogQueryManager: Failed to list tables
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet successfully received from the server was 476
>   milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was
>   465 milliseconds ago.
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:203)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.negotiateSSLConnection(MysqlIO.java:4901)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1659)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2188)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2219)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2014)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:776)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:386)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:904)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:59)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.listTables(CatalogQueryManager.java:102)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListTablesTool.run(ListTablesTool.java:49)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
>          at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252) Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Fri Jan 19
>   14:35:17 EST 2018
>           at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
>           at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
>           at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
>           at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514)
>           at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
>           at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
>           at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
>          at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:188)
>           ... 27 more Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Fri Jan 19
>   14:35:17 EST 2018
>           at sun.security.x509.CertificateValidity.valid(CertificateValidity.java:274)
>           at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(X509CertImpl.java:629)
>           at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(X509CertImpl.java:602)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled$X509TrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(ExportControlled.java:286)
>           at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:985)
>           at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
>           ... 35 more 18/07/10 12:18:46 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet successfully received from the server was 476
>   milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was
>   465 milliseconds ago. java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet successfully received from the server was 476
>   milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was
>   465 milliseconds ago.
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.listTables(CatalogQueryManager.java:118)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListTablesTool.run(ListTablesTool.java:49)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252) Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet successfully received from the server was 476
>   milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was
>   465 milliseconds ago.
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:203)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.negotiateSSLConnection(MysqlIO.java:4901)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1659)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2188)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2219)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2014)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:776)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:386)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:904)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:59)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.listTables(CatalogQueryManager.java:102)
>           ... 7 more Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Fri Jan 19
>   14:35:17 EST 2018
>           at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
>           at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
>           at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
>           at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514)
>           at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
>           at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
>           at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:188)
>           ... 27 more Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Fri Jan 19
>   14:35:17 EST 2018
>           at sun.security.x509.CertificateValidity.valid(CertificateValidity.java:274)
>           at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(X509CertImpl.java:629)
>           at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(X509CertImpl.java:602)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled$X509TrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(ExportControlled.java:286)
>           at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:985)
>           at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
>           ... 35 more

Answer (score 0):

Please try this -

1) go to my.cnf

2) Comment bind-address(As it is accepting to local connections only)

"bind-address = 127.0.0.1"

to

"#bind-address = 127.0.0.1"

3) Restart mysql

Also check this-

[jdbc mysql communications link failure to remote database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835800/jdbc-mysql-communications-link-failure-to-remote-database][1])